# Можете сказать,правильно ли я сделал push_front() для List(я делаю двусвязный список)

Tags: c++

````
using namespace std;


class Number{
public:
  int number;
  Number* ptr_on_next_forCurr;
  Number* ptr_on_prev_forCurr;
  
  Number(int number){
    this->number = number;
    this->ptr_on_next_forCurr = NULL;
    this->ptr_on_prev_forCurr = NULL;
  }
};


class List{
public:
  Number* ptr_on_Next;
  Number* ptr_on_Prev;
  
  List(){
    this->ptr_on_Next = NULL;
    this->ptr_on_Prev = NULL;
  }
  
  Number* push_front(int number){
    Number* ptr_on_curr = new Number(number);
    
    if(ptr_on_Next == NULL) // -> первый элемент списка
       ptr_on_Next = ptr_on_curr;
       
    else if(ptr_on_Next != NULL){
       ptr_on_curr->ptr_on_next_forCurr = ptr_on_Next;
       ptr_on_Next->ptr_on_prev_forCurr = ptr_on_curr;
       ptr_on_Next = ptr_on_Curr;
    }
    
    return ptr_on_curr;
  }
};


int main() 
{
    List lst;
    
    lst.push_front(100);
    lst.push_front(200);
    
    
    return 0;
}```
````